# JBoss AS7 Service Wrapper problems

Tags: java, jboss, wrapper

I'm trying to use Java Service Wrapper 3.3.5 32 bit community release with JBoss AS7 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  I have a hunch the reason I'm having problems is due our 32 bit version, but we have been able to use the 32 bit version of jsw with other applications (ActiveMQ) successfully, so I thought I'd try the 32 bit version first.  If it's advisable to upgrade to the pro version we will do so.

I'm pasting my wrapper.log and wrapper.conf below.  Right now the service is not able to start normally.  I tried troubleshooting the UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-32 in java.library.path error by making sure jsw was finding my java.library.path by hard coding paths for JAVA_HOME and JBOSS_HOME in my conf.

wrapper.log...

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.9
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | The file "D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin\wrapper.exe" is signed and the signature was verified.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   Signer Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |       00 97 06 fe b5 6e 56 cc cb 66 3a bb 55 a7 a0 e4 76 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Subject Name: Tanuki Software Ltd.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   TimeStamp Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |       47 8a 8e fb 59 e1 d8 3f 0c e1 42 d2 a2 87 07 be 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Subject Name: COMODO Time Stamping Signer
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |     Date of TimeStamp : 2011/05/09 01:37
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Release time: 2011/05/09 00:00:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Build time:   2011/05/09 18:36:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Timezone:     Pacific Standard Time (Pacific Daylight Time) Offset: 28800, hasDaylight: 1
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Using tick timer.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Current User: Administrator  Domain: IP-0A60A398
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Operating System ID: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2, Datacenter Edition Service Pack 2 (build 3790)
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | 
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Environment variables (Source | Name=Value) BEGIN:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _PARAMETERS= 
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _REALPATH=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_BASE=wrapper
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_CONF="../conf/wrapper.conf"
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_CONF_DEFAULT=../conf/wrapper.conf
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_EXE=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin\wrapper.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_L_EXE=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin\wrapper-windows-x86-32.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | APPDATA=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | CLIENTNAME=JAMIEWORK
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | ClusterLog=C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\cluster.log
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | COMPUTERNAME=IP-0A60A398
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | HOMEDRIVE=C:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | HOMEPATH=\Documents and Settings\Administrator
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---C | JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---C | JBOSS_HOME=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | LOGONSERVER=\\IP-0A60A398
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=1
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | OS=Windows_NT
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_REVISION=1a05
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | PROMPT=$P$G
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#3
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | SystemDrive=C:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | TEMP=C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | TMP=C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | USERDOMAIN=IP-0A60A398
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | USERNAME=Administrator
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P---- | windir=C:\WINDOWS
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_ARCH=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BIN_DIR=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BITS=32
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_CONF_DIR=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\conf
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_FILE_SEPARATOR=\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOST_NAME=ip-0A60A398
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOSTNAME=ip-0A60A398
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   P--W- | WRAPPER_INIT_DIR=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_LANG=en
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_OS=windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PATH_SEPARATOR=;
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PID=4432
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_WORKING_DIR=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Environment variables END:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Use tick timer mutex=FALSE
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | active log file changed: ..\standalone\log\wrapper.log
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | server listening on port 32001.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Ping settings: wrapper.ping.interval=5, wrapper.ping.interval.logged=1, wrapper.ping.timeout=30
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | Command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\java" -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false -Dlogging.configuration=file:D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl -Djava.library.path="../lib" -classpath "D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\lib\wrapper.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16/lib/tools.jar;D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/run.jar;D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar" -Dwrapper.key="2DBcrdYsF4TkOie9" -Dwrapper.port=32001 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=4432 -Dwrapper.version="3.5.9" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\bin\run.jar -mp D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\modules -logmodule org.jboss.logmanager -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:40 | JVM started (PID=5064)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main   Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: JVM #1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Running a 32-bit JVM.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager package information:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Title: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Vendor: Tanuki Software, Ltd.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Version: 3.5.9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Is Sealed?: False
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager protection domain:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Location: file:/D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/lib/wrapper.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:     Size: 118,538
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:     MD5: 0bb27af3979eaf3a593af1a3d63e9367
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Registering shutdown hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Using wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Load native library. One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.  This is NORMAL and is only a problem if they all fail.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Unable to load native library: wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll  Cause: no wrapper-windows-x86-32 in java.library.path
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Loaded native library: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Loaded native localization method.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Calling native initialization method.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJNI Debug: Initializing WrapperManager native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJNI Debug: Java Executable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\java.exe
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJNI Debug: Native Library: D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\lib\wrapper.dll
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJNI Debug: Windows version: 5.2.3790
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Java Version   : 1.6.0_16-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Java VM Vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Name        : Windows 2003
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Arch        : x86
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: Jar Main-Class: org.jboss.Main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: Jar Classpath: ../client/getopt.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug:     Classpath[0]=file:D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/run.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug:     Classpath[1]=file:D:/jboss-as-7.0.0.Final/bin/../client/getopt.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp@14693c7, args["-mp", "D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\modules", "-logmodule", "org.jboss.logmanager", "-jaxpmodule", "javax.xml.jaxp-provider", "org.jboss.as.standalone", "-Djboss.home.dir=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final"]) called by thread: main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Control event monitor thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Startup runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Communications runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Unable to open socket to Wrapper from port 31,000, already in use.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Unable to open socket to Wrapper from port 31,001, already in use.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Opened Socket from 31,002 to 32,001
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | Pause reading child process output to share cycles.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31002
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | closing backend server.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | read a packet KEY : 2DBcrdYsF4TkOie9
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | Got key from JVM: 2DBcrdYsF4TkOie9
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | send a packet LOGFILE : ..\standalone\log\wrapper.log
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | Start Application.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | send a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet KEY : 2DBcrdYsF4TkOie9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: handleBackend()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet LOGFILE : ..\standalone\log\wrapper.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Java temporary directory: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: calling WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: invoking main method
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: main method completed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperJarApp Debug: start(args) end.  Main Completed=true, exitCode=null
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: returned from WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet STARTED : 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | jboss: unused non-option argument: D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\modules
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | jboss: unused non-option argument: org.jboss.logmanager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | jboss: option '-j, --jaxp' no longer supported
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: ShutdownHook started
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet STOP : 0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Startup runner thread stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Stopped checking for control events.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | read a packet STARTED : 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | JVM signaled that it was started.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | read a packet STOP : 0
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | wrapperStopProcess(0, FALSE) called.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | Sending stop signal to JVM
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | send a packet STOP : NULL
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet STOP : 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: calling listener.stop()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperJarApp Debug: stop(0)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: returned from listener.stop() -> 0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: shutdownJVM(0) Thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: wait for 0 shutdown locks to be released.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet STOPPED : 0
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | read a packet STOPPED : 0
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | JVM signaled that it was stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Closing backend connection.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Closed backend socket: java.net.SocketException: socket closed
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Returned from backend handler.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | socket read no code (closed?).
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2011/09/08 08:17:42 | closing backend socket.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:43 | WrapperManager Debug: Server daemon shut down
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:43 | WrapperManager Debug: ShutdownHook complete
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:43 | JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:43 | JVM exited normally.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/09/08 08:17:43 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

wrapper.conf...

```
#encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
#wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
#wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:

set.JBOSS_HOME=D:\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final
set.JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/run.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%JBOSS_HOME%/*.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false
wrapper.java.additional.7=-    Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_HOME%/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.8=-    Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=128

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=512

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\run.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-mp
wrapper.app.parameter.3=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules
wrapper.app.parameter.4=-logmodule
wrapper.app.parameter.5=org.jboss.logmanager
wrapper.app.parameter.6=-jaxpmodule
wrapper.app.parameter.7=javax.xml.jaxp-provider
wrapper.app.parameter.8=org.jboss.as.standalone
wrapper.app.parameter.9=-Djboss.home.dir=%JBOSS_HOME%
```

Anyone know what's going on?  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS7 has changed in several ways how it is launching.

You are using Integration method 1, however it seems that you are passing in a jar file as the first parameter to org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp. WrapperSimpleApp expects the name of your main class as parameter. So you should go for integration method 4 and pass the jar file to org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp.

We have had some guys recently with the same questions and helped them resolving the problem:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1547

Hope this information helps you out.

Comment: Thanks, I've been following your advice and used method 4.  I believe I'm pretty close to making it work.  Right now I'm receiving the error message

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2011/09/08 08:17:41 | WrapperManager Debug:   Unable to load native library: wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll  Cause: no wrapper-windows-x86-32 in java.library.path

It seems like wrapper is not able to load the native library?  I'm not sure why this is - I've made sure that java.library.path config option points to the location of a valid wrapper.dll file.

Comment: I've edited my question to show the most recent version of my wrapper.conf and the latest results from wrapper.log, if you can take a look.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To me, based on what I see in the following line,  it appears that your arguments to the JVM might be off a little?   This error is unusual looking:

> WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class -mp:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -mp

In order for this to work, doesn't the main class in JBoss AS7  need to extend the tanukisoftware  service  interface class?    I realize that extending that class isn't required but I do know that if JBoss didn't extend it, then you wont have some of the functionality that you might be trying to use from the wrapper.

Therefor, if you get TOTALLY stuck, you could create your own secondary wrapper class that extends the tanuki wrapper  and it  calls the JBoss main class from itself.   Sorta like a simple wrapper around the tanuki wrapper.